# "server" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

Tags: docker, nginx, ssl, docker-compose

I'm trying to serve HTML files via a nginx server with SSL inside a docker container

This is the nginx.conf

```
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
  server {
    listen 9001 ssl;
    server_name example.com;

ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;

# Root directory for serving HTML files
root /usr/share/nginx/html;
index index.html;

location / {

}


}

}
```

This is the Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx:1.21

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY ./certs/server.crt /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt
COPY ./certs/server.key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key
COPY ./httpd_files  /usr/share/nginx/html
```

This is the docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  nginx:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 9001:9001
```

I'm trying to run  the conatiner using **docker-compose up** command

I get this error =>  **"server" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf**

attached a screenshot for clarity [image: here]

I have already tried lot of solutions found online. Thanks in advance